# jquery selecting part of the id

Tags: jquery, selector, partial, selectall

I have a few checkboxes that I would like to do a 'Select All' option for.
Id or name for those checkboxes is 'chk1', 'chk2', chk3.....
and the id for the selector checkbox is 'SelectAll'

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SelectAll').click(function () {
             $('input[name^="chk"]').attr("checked", this.checked);
        })
    })
```

the code works fine the first time I select and unselect but doesn't work after the subsequent clicks..
pls help.

Comment: Try using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead - `$('input[name^="chk"]').prop('checked', this.checked);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SelectAll').on('change', function() {
        $('input[name^="chk"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZUqf/1/)

Comment: @roasted - change would be the proper event for when a checkbox changes, even if it's changed with the keyboard, clicking a label etc.

Comment: Look like the problem was attr. @adenao, you are right, change should be use in all case, i was just wondering